# Save canvas as png without prompt in html/javascript Air app

Tags: javascript, canvas, air

I am using html2canvas in order to create a screenshot of a section of the app. I do have working code but it prompts the user to save. I would like the png to save without prompting.

Here is my WORKING code (but has user prompt):

```
html2canvas( $('#renderCover'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var base64ToByteArray = function(encStr){
            var base64s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
             var decOut = new air.ByteArray();  
            var bits;

            for(var i = 0, j = 0; i<encStr.length; i += 4, j += 3){
                bits = (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i)) & 0xff) <<18 | (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +1)) & 0xff) <<12 | (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +2)) & 0xff) << 6 | base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +3)) & 0xff;
                decOut[j+0] = ((bits & 0xff0000) >> 16);
                  if(i+4 != encStr.length || encStr.charCodeAt(encStr.length - 2) != 61){
                       decOut[j+1] = ((bits & 0xff00) >> 8);
                  }
                  if(i+4 != encStr.length || encStr.charCodeAt(encStr.length - 1) != 61){
                       decOut[j+2] = (bits & 0xff);
                  }
            }

            return decOut;
        };

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        dataURL = base64ToByteArray(dataURL);
        var file = air.File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Air Test/testPNG.png"); 
        file.save(dataURL); 
      }
    });
```

Here is my attempt without prompt but I'm getting error, Type Coercion failed:

```
html2canvas( $('#renderCover'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var base64ToByteArray = function(encStr){
            var base64s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
             var decOut = new air.ByteArray();  
            var bits;

            for(var i = 0, j = 0; i<encStr.length; i += 4, j += 3){
                bits = (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i)) & 0xff) <<18 | (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +1)) & 0xff) <<12 | (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +2)) & 0xff) << 6 | base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +3)) & 0xff;
                decOut[j+0] = ((bits & 0xff0000) >> 16);
                  if(i+4 != encStr.length || encStr.charCodeAt(encStr.length - 2) != 61){
                       decOut[j+1] = ((bits & 0xff00) >> 8);
                  }
                  if(i+4 != encStr.length || encStr.charCodeAt(encStr.length - 1) != 61){
                       decOut[j+2] = (bits & 0xff);
                  }
            }

            return decOut;
        };

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        dataURL = base64ToByteArray(dataURL);

        var storage = 'documentsDirectory';
        var localFile = air.File[storage].resolvePath( "Air Test/testPNG.png" );
        var stream = new air.URLStream();
        stream.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, function(e){
            var fileData = new air.ByteArray();
            stream.readBytes(fileData,0,stream.bytesAvailable);
            var fileStream = new air.FileStream();
            fileStream.openAsync(localFile, air.FileMode.WRITE);
            fileStream.writeBytes(fileData,0);
            fileStream.close();
        });
        stream.load(dataURL);


      }
    });
```

Is there any way to save the canvas as png local without a user prompt?

Comment: <a download='myfile.png' href="data:image/png,...">.click()

Comment: Thanks, but that would require the user to click another button and I think that would still prompt for the save location. I want the file to be saved with no user interaction.

Comment: no, js can call click() on the link, no user intervention required to trigger the download... if it asks where to save or not depends on browser settings, not js code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I fixed it myself. Here is the working code to save the canvas as a .png locally without user prompt:

```
html2canvas( $('#renderCover'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var base64ToByteArray = function(encStr){
            var base64s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
            var decOut = new air.ByteArray();  
            var bits;

            for(var i = 0, j = 0; i<encStr.length; i += 4, j += 3){
                bits = (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i)) & 0xff) <<18 | (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +1)) & 0xff) <<12 | (base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +2)) & 0xff) << 6 | base64s.indexOf(encStr.charAt(i +3)) & 0xff;
                decOut[j+0] = ((bits & 0xff0000) >> 16);
                  if(i+4 != encStr.length || encStr.charCodeAt(encStr.length - 2) != 61){
                       decOut[j+1] = ((bits & 0xff00) >> 8);
                  }
                  if(i+4 != encStr.length || encStr.charCodeAt(encStr.length - 1) != 61){
                       decOut[j+2] = (bits & 0xff);
                  }
            }
            return decOut;
        };

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        dataURL = base64ToByteArray(dataURL);

        var storage = 'documentsDirectory';
        var localFile = air.File[storage].resolvePath( "Air Test/testPNG.png" );
        var stream = new air.FileStream();
        stream.open(localFile, air.FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeBytes(dataURL,0);
        stream.close();
      }
});
```